# CSS Gallery IE Issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, gallery

I've got this image gallery, and it works in other browsers, but not IE, and I'm stumped as to why. I'm testing it on IE9 on Windows 7. It loads the default image and shows everything, but doesn't change images when the thumbnail is clicked. Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.image-gallery{
position:absolute;
  width:600px;
left:25%;

padding:20px;
}
.image-gallery .big-image{
  width:605px;
  height:450px;
  padding:1px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:white;  
}
.image-gallery .big-image img{
  display:none;
  margin:0 auto;
#menu{
position:absolute;
 left:2%;
top:2%;

}

}
/*Selected image display*/
.image-gallery .big-image img:target{display:block;}
/*on select image dusplay none the default image*/
.image-gallery .big-image img:target ~ img#default{display:none;}
/*Shoe Default Image in first load*/
.image-gallery .big-image img#default{display:block;}

.image-gallery ul{margin-top:1px;}
.image-gallery li{float:left;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-right:3px;}
.image-gallery li:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}



</style>
```

Now the body part

```
<div class="image-gallery">
<div class="title">Welcome to Jenny's Farm!</div>
<div class="big-image">           
      <img id="img1" src="gallery/1.jpg" />
      <img id="img1" src="gallery/2.jpg" />
      <img id="img3" src="gallery/3.jpg" />
      <img id="default" src="gallery/1.jpg" />
</div></div>
<div id="menu">
   <a href="#img1"><img  src="gallery/1.jpg" height="50" width="75" /></a>

  <a href="#img2"><img  src="gallery/2.jpg" height="50" width="75" /></a>

   <a href="#img3"><img  src="gallery/3.jpg" height="50" width="75" /></a>
```

Any suggestions? I'm using only CSS, no JS of any kind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, think it's because of you're using the `default` pseudo-element which is not supported by IE.
To check browser availability for different CSS elements and other things this site is  recommendable: http://caniuse.com  (Maybe there are other or better sites, but just to get the idea).

Just have a look for default: http://caniuse.com/#search=default

Comment: The default picture shows up on loading. When removed, nothing shows up and clicking the images still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, was a guess ;) But for :target e.g. IE8 is only partly supported (means some reported it won't work or some IE8 versions won't support it, can't guarantee their sources).

Comment: But just noticed - is this the original css you're using? Looks like some brackets are misplaced (the #menu e.g. closes with two, 2nd closing is the closing bracket from the style above ending with img).

Comment: I just corrected my crappy coding (thanks for pointing it out, I would have missed it for ages!) and its still doing the same thing. Click. The URL changes to site.html#img3 or whatever, but no image shows up. I think I'm going to make something different.

Comment: Glad I had a look and was a bit of service ;) Good luck. In case css won't work for IE, just have a look at some jquery / javascript for this kind of functionality.